# What kind of inductor is used in the SMD pi-filter? Air core or ferromagnetic core?

Tags: surface-mount, magnetics, passive-filter

What kind of inductor is used in an SMD pi-filter (LC) such as the [LFCN-80](https://www.minicircuits.com/pdfs/LFCN-80.pdf)? Air core or ferromagnetic core? Is it affected by external high magnetic fields (4 Tesla)?

Comment: Only one way to know ... Try one circuit test while measuring VSWR.

Comment: Other way to know : ask MiniCircuits FAE (or dstributor's FAE). Ther emay be a general datasheet or book for that series of parts.